# How to change app()->name dynamically in Yii?

Tags: yii, application-name

I am developing a website using Yii. I want to change the application name dynamically in program. I know I have to change the Yii::app()->name value. But I know where should I put it to overwrite what is written in config.php file.

Where should I put it?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to change the app name? @iodragon is right, this can be quite dangerous. And please give a better reason than "I need it" ;).

Answer (score 3):

$name is a public value of CApplication, you can just set it theoretically.

But this is not a good idea, the name is used in getId() function, and the id is used as keyPrefix in cache and maybe anywhere else. So **don't change the application name dynamically**.

If what you want is changing the page title dynamically, you can just set the CController::$pageTitle.

Comment: I need it. I am developing a CMS. So I have to change app name from a value in database table.

Comment: so you can just set it and be careful.

Comment: How can I set it? it is my question.

Comment: Yii::app()->name = "you value";

Answer (score 1):

Old question maybe but I just spent an hour fixing this and couldnt find an easy fix so here it is:

You can change Yii::app()->name dynamically as long as you are not using any caching component.

If you are using caching you can **still set the name variable dynamically if you give the entire application a static id** (the id variable of the CApplication class).

This is because the CWebUser component prefixes a stateKeyPrefix variable to the session lookup, which if not set looks for the CApplication id which if not set is a hashed version of the application name. So if you set either of these variables in your configuration file you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to change it? Anywhere you are displaying `Yii::app()->name` just use something like `getAppName()` and write a function to pull it out of the database.